# Paper trail association

Tags: paper-trail-gem

the object of my model has an association key and when the field with the key changes in the history, it is shown that the key of my object has changed, and I need to display not the key itself, but for example, the 'name' field of the object associated with the key, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. you can add a name column to your versions table (https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata)
2. you can use the `https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking` (https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4b-associations) which is currently compatible with PT < 12 (https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking/issues/27)